# Mapping a single child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

The mapping below works, but I was wondering if it can be done with less configuration. I've tried playing around with `ForAllMembers` and `ForSourceMember` but I haven't found anything that works so far.

**Classes**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    public int Group { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class UserForAuthorisation
{
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    public int Group { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**Configuration**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Session, UserForAuthorisation>()
    .ForMember(u => u.LoginName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.User.LoginName))
    .ForMember(u => u.Group, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.User.Group));
```

**Query**

```
UserForAuthorisation user = this.DbContext.Sessions
    .Where(item =>
        item.ID == SessionID
        )
    .Project().To<UserForAuthorisation>()
    .Single();
```

---

**Edit** This works for the reverse.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserForAuthorisation, User>();

Mapper.CreateMap<UserForAuthorisation, Session>()
    .ForMember(s => s.User, m => m.MapFrom(u => u));

var source = new UserForAuthorisation()
{
    Group = 5,
    LoginName = "foo"
};
var destination = Mapper.Map<Session>(source);
```

Unfortunately, `Reverse()` isn't the easy solution, mapping doesn't work.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserForAuthorisation, User>().ReverseMap();

Mapper.CreateMap<UserForAuthorisation, Session>()
    .ForMember(s => s.User, m => m.MapFrom(u => u)).ReverseMap();

var source = new Session()
{
    User = new User()
    {
        Group = 5,
        LoginName = "foo"
    }
};
var destination = Mapper.Map<UserForAuthorisation>(source);
```

Comment: Because you're flattening, and want to map both ways, I don't think you can get much simpler. I tend to just use profiles and hide the configuration away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see only one option to do less configurations. You can use benefit of [flattering](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) by renaming properties of `UserForAuthorisation` class to:

```
public class UserForAuthorisation
{
    public string UserLoginName { get; set; }
    public int UserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

In this case properties of nested `User` object will be mapped without any additional configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Session, UserForAuthorisation>();
```

Comment: Less configuration indeed, unfortunately that means having code like `user.UserLoginName`. +1 but I'll wait to see if there's a better answer.

Comment: @Stijn thanks for accepting, and yes `user.UserLoginName` is not best code, but that's how flattering works. Actually it's not very complex to specify several `ForMember` mappings, 2-3 minutes of time I think. So I'd spend that time to have `user.LoginName` instead :)

Comment: Agree, it's not much work, but I figured asking wouldn't hurt :) The official documentation isn't very comprehensive.